# Why does spring-boot include compile transitive dependencies from a test direct dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, java-17

I am generating my build and I am seeing deployed with my microservice compile transitive dependencies such as log4j, that came with a direct test dependency such as spring-boot-starter-test. That is also confirmed when I run `mvn dependency:tree` and gets the output below:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ payments-infrastructure ---
com.enterprise.project:payments-infrastructure:jar:1.0.0
+- com.enterprise.project:payments-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
|  +- com.enterprise.project:lib-java-tokenized:jar:1.0.0:compile
|  |  \- com.enterprise.project:lib-java-commons:jar:1.0.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.9:compile
|  \- org.json:json:jar:20211205:compile
+- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
|  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
|  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
|  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
+- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:4.0.0:test
|  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
|     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:test
|     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
|     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.3:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
|  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.33:compile
|  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.3:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.3:test
|  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:test
|  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
|  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
|  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
|  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
|  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
|  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
|  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
|  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.15:test
|  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
+- com.enterprise.project:lib-java-payment-commons:test-jar:tests:1.0.0:test
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.33:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.7:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
|  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.8.2:compile
|     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
|     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.56:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
|     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
|     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
+- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
|  |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  +- com.ecwid.consul:consul-api:jar:1.4.5:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
|  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
|  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-config:jar:3.1.0:compile
|     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.0:compile
|        \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.6.1:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.15:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |     \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.46.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.15:compile
|  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.73.Final:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.15:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.15:compile
|     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.14:compile
|        \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
+- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:7.0.1:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.1:compile
\- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:jar:1.6.2:compile
   +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:jar:1.6.2:compile
   |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.6.2:compile
   |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.11:compile
   |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.11:compile
   |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:jar:2.1.11:compile
   |     |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.11:compile
   |     |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.1:compile
   |     \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.116:compile
   +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:4.1.3:compile
   \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.48:compile
```

Following my dependencies list:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.enterprise.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>payments-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.enterprise.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-java-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I edited the dependencies above and placed exclusions for log4j in the spring-boot-starter-test and the log4j dependencies were gone. But I tested in another project that I have only three dependencies and none of them is spring-boot-starter-test and log4j shows up again, which leads me to my first question, why log4j were gone from the first project if I just placed exclusions in spring-boot-starter-test?

Here's the exclusions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And here's my second project dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And a second question is, shouldn't all the transitive dependencies be excluded from my final jar independent to its scope to a direct test dependency? I mean, shouldn't log4j not be included in my final jar since it is inherited by a direct test dependency?

Comment: are you asking about running a Maven dependency tree analysis that is limited to the `compile` scope?

Comment: No, I am asking why log4j, for example, is being deployed with my final jar since it is inherited from a test-scoped dependency.

Comment: do you have a link to your pom.xml? I tried to reproduce this and found that `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1` are transitive dependencies of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.6.3:compile`

Comment: I will edit the question with my dependencies.

Comment: But I double checked and it seems that log4j is coming from spring-boot-starter-test. I used CTRL + F on chrome with this question opened besides Eclipse dependency resolution screen.

Comment: I think this may be a issue on how maven displays the dependency tree, I thought log4j was being deployed because of spring-boot-starter-actuator because that is not clear on how maven displays it but I edited my pom and placed exclusion on the spring-boot-starter-test and log4j dependencies were gone. But in another project with just webflux and actuator in same versions as the first project log4j is being checked because of actuator.

Comment: yes, I verified that with the `./mvnw dependency:tree -Dscope=compile` command. the log4j dependencies are being brought in, transitively, through `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

Comment: Can you see my edit about the exclusions?

Comment: yes, the `log4j` dependencies are no longer being brought in with `spring-boot-starter-test`, they are still being brought in with `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

Comment: @asifafasih, if you rerun `mvn dependency:tree`, you'll see that now they are not being brought at all.

Comment: I was not able to see that. when I provided the `log4j` exclusions for the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency, it was excluded when I ran `./mvnw dependency:tree` in both IntelliJ and GitBash.

Comment: I'll check it out one more time and I'll get back at you ASAP.

Comment: Has this been resolved? Then I'd like to know how :)